# React JS:Download the file in JSON Format on clicking the download button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to download the file pertaining to that row with the value passed on from that row's values, The file is getting created and downloaded even before I click the download button , I am using react-file-download package and filedownload method for the same , but unable to do so. I need inputs on how to resolve this :

```
class displayBlank {

handleDownload(col 1,col2)
{

    var data = "This is an example JSON";
    var fileDownload = require('react-file-download');
    fileDownload(data, 'filename.json');

}

render(){
                    <table >
                      <thead>
                        <tr role="row">
                          <th>COL 1</th>
                          <th>COL 2</th>
                          <th>COL 3</th>
                          <th>COL 4</th>
                          <th>COL 5</th>
                          <th>COL 6</th>
                          <th>COL 7</th>
                          <th>COL 8</th>
                          <th>COL 9</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {this.state.pageOfItems.map((item, i) => {
                          return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                              <td >{item.COL1}</td>
                              <td> {item.COL2}</td>
                              <td> {item.COL3}</td>  
                              <td> {item.COL4}</td>  
                              <td> {item.COL5}</td>
                              <td> {item.COL6}</td>
                              <td style={{color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', backgroundColor: item.COL 7 === 'VALUE' ? 'red' : 'green'}}>{item.COL7}</td>
                              <td >{item.COL 8 === 'VALUE1' ? (<div><Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit" bsSize="small" onClick={this.handleDownload(item.COL1,item.COL2)}>DOWNLOAD</Button></div>) : (<div></div>)}</td>
                            </tr>
                          );
                        })}


                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    }
                    }
```

The file gets downloaded even before clicking the download button and the particular row values are not being passed onto the handleDownload function.

Comment: There are tons of syntax errors in that code; you can't have spaces in variable names or keys. Other than that, `onClick={this.handleDownload(...)}` will a) call `this.handleDownload(...)` b) set `onClick` to what was returned from the call. See the answer you got for one way to fix this.

Comment: @ChrisG I have fixed the spaces , Thanks

Comment: After fixing the syntax and onclick issues, it works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/w2x2xrp53w

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks Chris , Worked Fine for me too , Some issue with my console settings on the browser , Thanks for the inputs. I am not sure how to select yours as the correct answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClick={() => this.handleDownload(item.COL 1,item.COL 2)}
```

You are calling the function, instead you should use callback like above.

Comment: True, I assume that is item.COL_1. But i've just copied and pasted his own code. My answer will solve his issue.

Comment: @prabinbadyakar Thanks for the inputs , I have edited my code which had spaces in variable names.I did try out your suggestion but the issue is even though the file downloads now only on clicking the download button , the values being passed like COL_1,COL_2 are not being retrieved in handledownload function, I am unable to print them out. Infact even if I just console.log('In handle download function') I am unable to do so.